# Attaching function to be used as an inline-style to componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React. I have a small function in vanilla JS that randomly generates a given image. Since its random, and not saved to any state (purposely), each state change also changes image as well, which is what I'm trying to avoid. The image will be used as an inline-style on `<body>`, so it can be used as my background-image.

If I set this `myBackground` function on `componentWillMount`, which renders only once right before component is mounted, then I can accomplish what I need, but I don't know what is expected to be there.

```
class homePage extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {}
  }

  get myBackground () {
    const imageArr = ['cat.jpg', 'dog.jpg', 'horse.jpg']
    const randomImg = imageArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArr.length)]
    const bgImg = {backgroundImage: 'url(' + randomImg + ')'}

    return bgImg
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    this.myBackground // doesn't work
  }

  render () {

    // with the current status, below image is changed
    // whenever a given state is changed. It needs to be changed
    // only right before component is mounted
    return <body style={this.myBackground}>
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I have `this.myBackground`attached to componentWillMount and yet be able to use it inside render? Please note that creating a `setState` to handle this behavior is not expected.

Comment: `this.myBackground // doesn't work` <-- what does it mean?

Comment: wait, what do you expect `this.myBackground` to do?

Comment: "doesn't work" means that every time there's a state change, the image is randomized again, but it should be random only before component is mounted

Comment: `this.myBackground` should return me a random image, mutable only if the component is mounted again

Comment: Why does your `myBackground` function have a `get` right before it? Is that function a getter function inside your React component class? If it is, then that is probably the problem.

Comment: @rclai89 it is just because I'm using an ES6 class constructor, just thought it's not important for the answer, so didn't include. All in if the answer needs it to be removed, just syntax sugar

Comment: It's not obvious what you want to achieve. If you want to have state in your component - use react's state and store the random index there.

Comment: If that getter function is defined in the same class, then it is always going to give you a new image in the `render` function every time the state changes. You need to use a different instance property name to store that image.

Comment: @zerkms sorry for not being precise. Actually I want to avoid having state here. Just want to have my random image to be random just before component is mounted, and not being randomized all the time some other state changes, because this is what happens currently.

Comment: Can you please write a more complete React class and actually complete what you actually did in `componentWillMount`? There are so many unknowns that don't help us help you.

Comment: "I want to avoid having state here" --- it makes very little sense. You want to avoid state but you want to have state. "and not being randomized all the time" --- that's called "state".

Comment: @zerkms not really. I want a random background, but don't want it to be random each time a user interact with my app. It should be random only when user get to see it.

Comment: That's correct. What you just explained **IS** a component state.

Comment: @zerkms so what I'm trying to accomplish isn't possible without the use of state?

Comment: You need to store state somewhere. In react the state is stored in `this.state`.

Comment: Depending on your flavor of React component class syntax, you can set your random image in the constructor initializing your state, or `getInitialState`. But technically, it should work as a class property, but you still haven't answered whether it is a getter function.

Comment: @rclai89 it is a getter, it is obvious from its syntax.

Comment: @rclai89 updated for you :)

Comment: In `componentWillMount` you need to use a different property name, to store the random image. `this.backgroundUsedInRender = this.myBackground`. Do you not see that when state changes, it is going to call your getter function again in `render`?

Comment: @rclai89 how is it different from using `this.state`? Apart from the fact that now state is spread over multiple places.

Comment: @zerkms I'm not saying it's "different" from `state`, I'm just trying to provide an answer based on his implementation style.

Comment: @rclai89 it makes sense, could you formulate an answer with more details?

Comment: @audaz802 it makes no sense, geez. People, why do you deliberately turn your code into spaghetti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `this.myBackground` inside render, which is a getter function. Every time your component re-renders, it is going to call the getter function again and give you another image.

Just change your getter function name to something else and store that into your instance property or `state` in `componentWillMount`.

```
class homePage extends React.Component {
  // Rename your getter function!
  get getNewBackground() {
    const imageArr = ['cat.jpg', 'dog.jpg', 'horse.jpg']
    const randomImg = imageArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArr.length)]
    const bgImg = {backgroundImage: 'url(' + randomImg + ')'}

    return bgImg
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.myBackground = this.getNewBackground;
  }

  render() {
    return <body style={this.myBackground}>
  }
}
```

In all seriousness, you should not be using getter functions like that, your component should look like this:

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      backgroundImage: this.getNewBackground(),
    };
  }

  getNewBackground() {
    const imageArr = ['cat.jpg', 'dog.jpg', 'horse.jpg'];
    const randomImg = imageArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArr.length)];
    const bgImg = {backgroundImage: 'url(' + randomImg + ')'};

    return bgImg;
  }

  render() {
    return <body style={this.state.myBackground}>
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be beneficial if you provided a proper solution as well. Otherwise novices would follow this terrible solution as-is. Yep, I changed my mind, that you can make this world better by improving the answer :-)

Comment: Yeah, honestly, I don't even know why he even used a getter function.

Comment: It surely is - semantically `this.state` is the place where you store the state. Spreading the state over random properties is confusing.

Comment: thank you both. Not only solves my problem but made me learn, and sure will help others. Our community is better with people like you. Thanks

Comment: Okay, glad we could get this resolved. It only took like... an hour LOL.